# not able to use cache in django python

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

i want to cache  in django so I am using low level API caching but even after adding it shows none

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!')
>>> cache.get('my_key')
>>> print(cache.get('my_key'))
None
>>>
```

in my settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

even when i use `cache.add('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)` it return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
```

this setting worked for me

Comment: This is what I use in development on my local machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set timeout:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'exchange_rate_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 604800  # 7 days
    }
}
```

You can set the timeout to None to remove it completely.

Comment: even after  using this also same result is coming